# Reading from text to draw points

Tags: c#, forms, graphics, streamreader

Greeting!
I want to read from a text which looks like this:

```
1111.49 2822.06 Aba
1235.94 2848.48 Abadszalok
1087.09 2768.63 Abaliget
```

The first number would be x and the second y. On a form with a button it would read the file and make them into dots something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("helyforr.txt");
        double[] x = new double[3124] //there is 3124 lines in the text;
        double[] y = new double[3124];
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string sor = sr.ReadLine();
            sor = sor.Replace('.', ','); //swap '.' to ',' make it double
            string[] r = sor.Split(' ');

            x[0] = Convert.ToDouble(r[0]);
            y[0] = Convert.ToDouble(r[1]);
            Graphics rl = this.CreateGraphics();
            rl.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), (Int32)x[0], (Int32)y[0], 1, 1);
        }
        sr.Close();
    }
```

However it does not work so if someone understand my idea (and my horrible English) and  able to help me i would really appreciate it!

Comment: What doesn't work? The reading and loading of the file, or the drawing of the dots?

Comment: Does it throw an exception? If so, at what line?
Also, you don't need to declare those double[]s as arrays - just make them doubles (not arrays) - you only ever use x[0] and y[0] in this code, not any of the other indexes.

Comment: `CreateGraphics` should probably be outside of the while loop - You need to describe what "does not work" entails in order for anyone to be able to help

Comment: `Andor_Horvath` look at this if you are not sure on [C# Arrays](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_arrays.htm) also have you even looked at MSDN `FillRectangle` or this site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ztxk24yx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't see anything because your y-coordinate most likely is way out of range, or has your Form really a height of 2700+ pixels?
2. This is not the right way to draw just about anything in winforms! Instead do this:

   - Create a `List<Rectangle> plotpoints` and fill it in your button click. Or a `List<Point>` or a `List<someClassOrStruct> which could include a`Color` and/or the Text from the file...
   - Decide onto which `Control` to draw. Instead of the `Form` it is much more flexible to use e.g. a `Panel`
   - `Invalidate()` that `Panel` each time your list of `plotPoints` has been updated
   - Code the `Panel`'s `Paint` event using the `Graphics` object in the event parameter!
3. Why is your way wrong? Well if you scale down the numbers you'll see some pixels but after you minimize the form and restore they will be gone. They are not persistent! To create persistent graphics you need to either draw **into** a `PictureBox's Image` or use any control's Paint event to let it draw **onto** the control whenever it is necessary. This means when either the **system** notices the need or when **you** call the `Invalidate` function!

So your button click could look something like this:

```
List<Rectangle> plotPoints = new List<Rectangle>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("helyforr.txt");
    double[] x = new double[3124] //there is 3124 lines in the text;
    double[] y = new double[3124];
    int scale = 10;    // I start with a scale down fastor of 10. 
           // you could also calculate it taking the size of the canvas into account..
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string sor = sr.ReadLine();
        sor = sor.Replace('.', ','); //swap '.' to ',' make it double
        string[] r = sor.Split(' ');

        x[0] = Convert.ToDouble(r[0]) / scale;
        y[0] = Convert.ToDouble(r[1]) / scale;

        plotPoints.Add(new Rectangle( (Int32)x[0], (Int32)y[0], 1, 1));
    }
    sr.Close();
    canvasPanel.Invalidate();
}
```

and your `Paint` event would look like this for a `Panel canvasPanel`:

```
private void canvasPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Rectangle r in plotPoints)
       e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), r);
}
```

4. Besides the issue of drawing there are other issues; most notably you have hard-coded the number of lines. I suggest replacing the two arrays by a  `List<PointF>` or a `List<someStructure>` that holds the numbers and the text.. This way your program can handle any file length.